# Spring JMS reading from Weblogic Cluster

Tags: java, spring, jms, weblogic

I have a standalone Spring application that reads messages from a Weblogic cluster.  It is not a MDP, rather it runs multiple threads that each use a JMSTemplate to browse the queue and retrieve messages based on specific criteria.

I would like to cache the JMS connections, while also ensuring that I open enough connections that I always am retrieving messages from each server in the cluster.  My issue is the default ConnectionFactory does not cache at all, but the Spring wrappers SingleConnectionFactory and CachingConnectionFactory do not allow for multiple connections open at once.

Should I implement my own ConnectionFactory that caches on a limited basis?  Or what is the recommended approach.

Answer (score 0):

Use case seemed to be quite clumsy to do in Spring, so resolved the issue by directly managing the JMS resources directly.